injective module in a short exact sequence

Let $Q$ be an injective module and $0 \rightarrow Q \xrightarrow{\lambda} M \xrightarrow{\mu} N \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence. Then the sequence splits.

I understand the proof of the dual problem with projective module saying if $N$ is projective then the sequence splits. I considered the extension of the identity map $i:Q=Q$ to $M$ (say $q: M \rightarrow Q$) such that $i = q \circ\lambda$, but how does this help to show that $M=Q\oplus N$? Even if $Q$ is not injective, still $\lambda$ is an embedding of $Q$ into $M$. Here $q$ is just sending $Q$ to $Q$. I need to show $M\setminus Q \xrightarrow{\mu}  N$ is an isomorphism.
proof from hint:
For $0\neq a \in \ker\hat{q}$, $\hat{q}(a)=0$ so $a \not\in \text{im}\lambda=\ker\mu$. Hence, $\mu:\ker\hat{q} \rightarrow N$ is injective.
For each $0\neq n \in N$, there exists $m \in M$ such that $\mu(m)=n$. Suppose $m \not\in \ker\hat{q}$. Then $\hat{q}(m)\neq 0$ in $Q$. Since $\lambda \circ \hat{q}$ is identity map from $Q$ to $Q$, there exists $a \in Q$ such that $\lambda(a)=m$, which means $m \in \text{im} \lambda=\ker\mu$. This is a contradiction as $n\neq0$. Hence, $\mu:\ker\hat{q} \rightarrow N$ is surjective.

Hint: Try to show that $\mu: \mathrm{Ker}(q)\to N$ is an isomorphism. $M\setminus \lambda(Q)$ is not even a submodule.

In the dual problem (with $N$ projective, and $s$ the splitting morphism) the book proof shows that $M$ is the direct sum of the images of $\lambda$ and $s$. Dualizing that leads to a way of showing that $M$ is the direct sum of two kernels (of $\mu$ and $q$). But I'm fairly sure this has been covered earlier (or in some other textbook).

Related 1, 2. Item 2 on that list points at a Wikipedia article. I could vote to close this as a duplicate of that, but my vote would be immediately binding, so I will wait for a while.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, I wrote my proof from your hint

Glad to hear that!
